# Limits of Nat type in Shapeless

Tags: scala, numbers, compiler-optimization, shapeless

In shapeless, the Nat type represents a way to encode natural numbers at a type level. This is used for example for fixed size lists. You can even do calculations on type level, e.g. append a list of `N` elements to a list of `K` elements and get back a list that is known at compile time to have `N+K` elements.

Is this representation capable of representing large numbers, e.g. `1000000` or 2<sup>53</sup>, or will this cause the Scala compiler to give up?

Comment: Miles's [NE Scala presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9w1PDnD5mPc) last year addresses this question, and the short answer is that it would be possible to represent large numbers at the type level in Scala—or at least in 2.10—using [singleton types](https://twitter.com/milessabin/status/278905905523879938), but it [might not be worth it](https://twitter.com/milessabin/status/422648354888491008). Shapeless 2.0 currently still uses the Church encoding, which will get you to 1,000 or so before the compiler gives up.

Comment: Thanks. If you post this as an answer I will mark it as answered. I will have to find another way to do what I want to do.

Comment: I'll try to write up an answer with a little more context later today. As a side note, it's not too hard to work with integer singleton types if you need larger type level numbers—see for example my blog post [here](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/28/singleton-types-for-literals-in-scala/) or the [singleton functionality in Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala).

Comment: If you want to do arithmetic on large type-level numbers, you may consider implementing them as a linked list of bits.

Comment: Yet one variant -- use trick with type-alias and unsafe cast to this alias with value [ see http://slick.typesafe.com/talks/scalaio2014/Type-Level_Computations.pdf ] slide 37, implementation can be found https://github.com/szeiger/ErasedTypes

Comment: @KarolS I have an implementation of that strategy! And I'd be glad to contribute it to shapeless if anyone is interested, although it's worthless unless someone can help solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768203/counting-with-shapeless-style-dense-binary-numbers

Comment: It looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768203/implicit-resolution-failure is solved, so can you contribute you code and close the question with your own answer ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I will attempt one myself. I will gladly accept a better answer from Travis Brown or Miles Sabin.

Nat can currently **not** be used to represent large numbers

In the current implementation of Nat, the value corresponds to the number of nested shapeless.Succ[] types:

```
scala> Nat(3)
res10: shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]] = Succ()
```

So to represent the number 1000000, you would have a type that is nested 1000000 levels deep, which would definitely blow up the scala compiler. The current limit seems to be about 400 from experimentation, but for reasonable compile times it would probably be best to stay below 50.

However, there is a way to encode large integers or other values at type level, *provided that you do not want to do calculations on them*. The only thing you can do with those as far as I know is to check if they are equal or not. See below.

```
scala> type OneMillion = Witness.`1000000`.T
defined type alias OneMillion

scala> type AlsoOneMillion = Witness.`1000000`.T
defined type alias AlsoOneMillion

scala> type OneMillionAndOne = Witness.`1000001`.T
defined type alias OneMillionAndOne

scala> implicitly[OneMillion =:= AlsoOneMillion]
res0: =:=[OneMillion,AlsoOneMillion] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[OneMillion =:= OneMillionAndOne]
<console>:16: error: Cannot prove that OneMillion =:= OneMillionAndOne.
       implicitly[OneMillion =:= OneMillionAndOne]
                 ^
```

This could be used to e.g. enforce same array size when doing bit operations on Array[Byte].

Comment: Just saw this answer, and +1, this is a good example. It's worth noting though that you _could_ provide type classes like e.g. Shapeless's `ops.nat.Sum` that would witness that two type-level integers had a particular sum, etc. (they'd just have to be provided by a macro).

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/fthomas/scala-macro/blob/c89139fbc0c4421d0ff3a82bf3e0adec368da5c2/src/main/scala/Concat.scala) is an example of a `Concat` type class that allows to concatenate two type-level strings via a macro. A type class for summing type-level integers would probably look very similar.

Answer (score 5):

Shapeless's `Nat` encodes natural numbers at the type level using Church encoding. An alternate method is to represent the naturals as a type level HList of bits.

Check out [dense](https://github.com/beefyhalo/dense) which implements this solution in a shapeless style.

*I haven't worked on it in a while, and it needs a sprinkling of shapeless' `Lazy` here and there for when scalac gives up, but the concept is solid* :)

Comment: I guess Church encoding of natural numbers is encoding them as lambdas `f => x => x`, `f => x => f(x)`, `f => x => f(f(x))`... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding Encoding them as `Z`, `S(Z)`, `S(S(Z))`... is by Peano https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms