# Materialize the Value for a Type that has One Inhabitant

Tags: scala, macros, implicit, shapeless, type-level-computation

Thanks to @MilesSabin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32157259/867671) I can write a type level Fibonacci sequence:

```
sealed trait Digit
case object Zero extends Digit
case object One extends Digit

sealed trait Dense { type N <: Dense }
sealed trait DNil extends Dense { type N = DNil }
case object DNil extends DNil
final case class ::[+H <: Digit, +T <: Dense](digit: H, tail: T) extends Dense {
  type N = digit.type :: tail.N
}

/* The `A`th Fibonacci number is `B` */
trait Fib[A <: Dense, B <: Dense]

object Fib {
  implicit val f0 = new Fib[_0, _0] {}
  implicit val f1 = new Fib[_1, _1] {}

  implicit def f2[A <: Dense, P <: Dense, P2 <: Dense, F <: Dense, F2 <: Dense]
   (implicit p: Pred.Aux[A, P],
             p2: Pred.Aux[P, P2],
             f: Fib[P, F],
             f2: Fib[P2, F2],
             sum: Sum[F, F2]): Fib[A, sum.Out] = new Fib[A, sum.Out] {}
}

implicitly[Fib[_7, _13]]
```

What I'd really like to be able to do is get a `Witness` for `Dense` and use it like:

```
def apply[Out <: Dense](n: Dense)(implicit f:Fib[n.N, Out], w:Witness.Aux[Out]): Out
  = w.value
```

Scala tells me that it can't summon a `Witness` instance. I'm guessing this is because my type-level encoding of natural numbers is a linked list of bits and that's not a singleton type. I can't understand why `Witness` won't work since there is only a single inhabitant for a class like `_7`.

What I'm trying to do is materialize a value for a type that only has one possible value. That way I can get an `Out` directly from `apply`.

I think a possible solution might leverage implicit macros.

Any and all ideas are welcome. I encourage you to leave a note if the question isn't clear.