# How to specify a shapeless singleton type ahead of time

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'd like to construct a type like `LimitedString[Limit]` where `Limit` is a type representation of the maximum length of the string.

It would work along the lines of

```
class LimitedString[Limit] [private](val s: String)
object LimitedString {
  private def getLimit[Limit]: Int = ??? // turn `Limit` type into a value
  def truncate[Limit](s: String) = new LimitedString[Limit](s take getLimit)
  def get[Limit](s: String) = 
    if(s.length < getLimit) Some(new LimitedString[Limit](s))
    else None
}

type Str100 = LimitedString[100] // obviously this won't work
def someLibraryMethod(s: Str100) = { ... }
```

What I can't figure out is how to actually type (as in keyboard) the type (as in compilation) for `Limit`.

I started looking into Shapeless's singleton types and found that you can say

```
100.narrow
// res1: Int(100) = 100
```

But if I try to use `Int(100)` as the type, I get errors.

```
val x: Int(100) = 100
// error: ';' expected but '(' found.
```

Additionally, how would I implement something like `def getLimit[Limit]: Int`?

Comment: Why not use Church encoding, through shapeless `Nat`. Representing numbers as types seems to be its exact purpose (for numbers < 400ish). If you need bigger, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296099/limits-of-nat-type-in-shapeless) for ideas/discussion on what to do with larger nums.

Comment: I can't give a full answer at the moment, but take a look at Shapeless's `Witness`, which allows you to refer to types like this as e.g. `Witness.\`100\`.T` as well as providing access to their runtime values.

Comment: @DavisBroda The intended Limit is in the neighborhood of 100. Would that mean I would have to write `Succ[Succ[Succ.....]]]` out to 100 levels in order to create my `Str100` type alias?

Comment: I think there are aliases that simplify specifying number types. I think there are also ways to get the correct value implicitly in some cases. Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with `Nat`. Thought I could point you - and other potential answerers - in the right direction, but lack the expertise to help with the specifics.

Comment: @DavisBroda alright, thank you for the link. I'll take a deeper look if Travis's suggestion doesn't pan out (although it looks like it will)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took @TravisBrown's suggestion to look into Shapless's `Witness`, and came up with this:

```
class LimitedString[Limit <: Int] private[util](val s: String) extends AnyVal {
    override def toString = s
}
class LimitedStringCompanion[Limit <: Int : Witness.Aux]{
    def limit: Int = implicitly[Witness.Aux[Limit]].value

    def unapply(s: String): Option[LimitedString[Limit]] = {
        if(s.length > limit) None else Some(new LimitedString(s))
    }

    def truncate(s: String): LimitedString[Limit] = new LimitedString(s take limit)
}
```

Usage:

```
import shapeless._

object MyLibraryThing {
  type Name = LimitedString[Witness.`50`.T]
  object Name extends LimitedStringCompanion[Witness.`50`.T]

  def rename(id: Int, name: Name) = { ... }
}
```

The key things that make it work:

- `Witness.Aux` is a typeclass which you can use to get the singleton `value` back out of the type
- The singleton type `` Witness.`50`.T `` is actually a subtype of `Int`
- Type aliases make it more convenient to interact with

Comment: One bummer about the "companion" is that the compiler won't automatically search it for implicits involving `Name` since `Name` is just a type alias.